# In Laravel 5, How to customize Session flash message with href

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.1

I'm showing **Please verify your email before login** in my login blade if user didn't verify his account through email link.

```
if ($user->is_verified == 0) {
    $request->session()->flash("failed", "Please verify your email before login );
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

And in my blade I do like this to catch it

```
@if (Session::has('failed'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
    {{Session::get('failed')}}.<br><br>
    </div>              
@endif
```

But Now I have to add this message **Please verify your email before login or resend the verification email** and make resend part with *href* to a route. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

In route.php add a route

```
Route::get('/resend_mail', 'VerificationMailController@resend'); //replace with your desired location
```

In VerificationMailController.php

```
public function resend(){
     //do your resend verification mail code
}
```

Than use this code where you want to show resend message

```
if ($user->is_verified == 0) {
$resendurl = route('resend_mail'); //here replace the route of your email verification send route.
$msg = 'Please verify your email before login or <a href="'.$resendurl.'">resend</a> the verification email';
    $request->session()->flash("failed",  $msg);
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Comment: No no.. I already do it. If accidentally user delete his verification email, he has no way to log to his account. Sometimes he forget to verify. So in that message I have to resend it

Comment: in what kind of format should I give the url there. Eg:- my route is **/resend_mail**

Comment: See the updated code. I think now you should got an idea how to deal with it

Comment: But I see it like this 
**Please verify your email before login or <a href="">resend</a> the verification email.**

Answer (score 2):

Finally I come up with this little changes to the codes.

My code in blade should change like this. Because otherwise it won't accept html syntax, just showing plan html. this is called [laravel escape html](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates).

```
@if (Session::has('failed'))
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
     {!!Session::get('failed')!!}.<br><br>
     </div>
@endif
```

[Md. Sahadat Hossain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2738927/md-sahadat-hossain) answer is correct. But accourding my issue I change his code like this.

```
if ($user->is_verified == 0) {                    
     $msg = 'Please verify your email before login or <a href="'. url("/resend_email").'">resend</a> the verification email';
     $request->session()->flash("failed",  $msg);
     return redirect('/login');
 }
```

and now it's showing like this as wht I want

[image]